# HP ALM Python rest api - How to properly pass cookie for API calls

Tags: python, rest, hp-alm

How to pass the HP ALM authentication session object for rest api calls. I am following some examples to connect to HP ALM via REST API to run basic CRUD operations.

One of the example - https://github.com/vkosuri/py-hpalm/blob/master/hpalm/hpalm.py

Below is the code snippet to establish the connection which is working perfectly fine. I am getting 200 OK response for login.

```
headers = {'Cookie' : lwssocookie}
headers["Accept"] = 'application/xml'
login_url = self.base_url + '/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate'

resp = requests.get(login_url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.username, self.password), verify=self.verify)
alm_session = resp.headers['Set-Cookie']
logger.debug("Is QC session launched: %s" %alm_session)
cookie = ";".join((lwssocookie, alm_session))
```

But all the subsequent operations are failing with unauthorized error even though I added the cookies to header

```
self.headers['cookie'] = cookie
url = self.base_url + '/qcbin/rest/domains/' + self.domain + '/projects/' + self.project + '/test-instances'
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=self.getheaders())
```

Can anyone please suggest how to hold the session to run operations and what am I missing here.

I also tried to pass cookies in get call as below and even that didn't work.

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=self.getheaders(), cookies=cookie)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [requests.Session()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/), there is no need to manipulate HTTP headers for cookies.

Here is a code snippet I run for old ALM version 12.01 which took me a couple of hours to design thanks to [this post](https://www.aneejian.com/2017/03/hp-alm-rest-api-authentication.html):

```
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False

auth = session.post(hpqc_server + "authentication-point/authenticate?login-form-required=y",
                    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
print("Authentication ", auth, auth.text, session.cookies)

site_session = session.post(hpqc_server + "rest/site-session")
print("Session ", site_session, site_session.text, session.cookies)

check = session.get(hpqc_server + "rest/is-authenticated")
print("Check ", check, check.text)

# Enforce JSON output
session.headers.update({ 'Accept': 'application/json' })
projects = session.get(hpqc_server + "rest/domains/DOMAIN/projects")
```